# Advice for improving internal dashboard

Tags: usability, layout, react

I work for a book manufacturer, a component from our internal dashboard looks like this:  [image].

I'm not a designer by trade and as it's come to refactoring the project, I figured now would be a good time to clean up the UX a bit.

The purpose of the component is to show the planned vs actual (jobs scheduled vs what we actually did) as simply as possible.

Should also specify that the buckets are a management request so they can't change but everything else is up in the air.

(The export expands into an export via email or straight CSV)

Any advice would be great! Sorry if the question is inappropriate.

Comment: It's a bit of a broad question currently. It reads more like 'please redesign this component for me' rather than a specific problem to solve. Can you narrow it down a bit? What is wrong with it currently? What isn't it doing that it should be? Is there a specific aspect of it that isn't working well? We can help solve specific problems, but can't give broad advice or do the full redesign for you.

Comment: @JonW I'm not asking for a redesign, just some advice. I personally feel like it could be simplified but I don't know how.

Comment: We can't 'simplify' it without redesigning it. And we'd need more context to know how to do that. For example, it would be more simple if the value field were removed, for instance. But we don't know what that is needed for. That's why we need specific aspects to fix, not something as broad as 'simplify' or 'redesign'. Have a look at the [Tour] page for a better overview of the site, and maybe [this advice post on our meta site](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-ux-stackexchange) that will help you structure the question slightly differently.

Comment: @JonW I found it pretty easy to answer in a basic way. Maybe some more information about what information is more important than others would have helped a wee bit, but I really didn't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on first review, that bucket thing (I thought was a glass) takes up all the room and I have no idea what it means.  It has no scale.

The main points of data are buried in text so you need to change that styling to emphasise the numbers and remove words.

It's something along the lines of [image]

You can change the pie into the red glass, the point is, tie in the chart to the numbers and bring out useful data while losing the text.

Comment: As specified, the buckets were a requirement by management but I appreciate the other information. Their logic is it's a measurement of what's been made out of what should be made (yes I know pie charts).

Comment: Use the bucket then! A lot of UX is trying to mitigate bad design decisions by the folks ;)